# UITableView cells repeating after 6, but showing correct data when clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I know this kind of question is been asked many times before.. but i'm very confused and not finding any solution even after a lot of searching..

I have a table in which cells are repeating after every 6th cell..  but the weird thing is, **if I click any of the repeated cell, it shows me correct data which it is supposed to show** in **didSelectRowAtIndexpath**  method..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     return  array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIImageView * cellImageView;
    NSArray *pathComponents;
    NSData *imageData;
    UIImage *image;
    UILabel * mainLabel = nil;

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"in loop");

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 15)]autorelease];

        [cell addSubview:mainLabel];
    }

    mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    mainLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:11];
    mainLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    mainLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]retain];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: check array.count in NSLog

Comment: Maybe it would help if mainLabel wasn't nil when you're setting its value.  (You need to extract mainLabel from the cell when you recycle.)

Comment: @DeepakKhiwani - That's a dumb idea.

Comment: i did check array.count.. it is exactly what I want.. 100

Comment: @Vish_Obj-C did that thing work for you?

Comment: @DeepakKhiwani - It might work, but you'd not be recycling cells, which would slow down scrolling.

Comment: @DeepakKhiwani i have around 100 cells with images on it. Here i didn't show the image ani the rest of the cell data..   so I am gonna have to use reuse feature of cells

Comment: i think problem with thread see my answer for reload data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714609/nsarray-values-are-display-after-touche-in-screen-in-tableview/16715224#16715224

Answer (score 4):

```
if (cell == nil)
{

    NSLog(@"in loop");

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


    mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 15)]autorelease];
    mainLabel.tag = 1234;

    [cell addSubview:mainLabel];
}
else {
    mainLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1234];
}
```

But in addition to the problem with recycling per se there are a couple of other issues.  For optimum performance all setup of the label -- operations that are the same every time -- should be done inside the `if` clause.  Only set the variable text in the main body of the method, after the if/else.

Additionally, if not using ARC, the label should be released after the addSubview call and before the end of the `if` clause.

And the label text should not be retained as its fetched from `array` -- the label will retain it.

Comment: It gets crashed after scrolling for sometime with no log

Comment: @objc_developer - Did you fix the problems with your retains?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting mainLabel attributes only first time.Keep your main label property settings in your condition if cell==nil

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

    UILabel *mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 15)]autorelease];
    mainLabel.tag=23;

    mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    mainLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    mainLabel.font  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:11];
    mainLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    [cell addSubview:mainLabel];
}

UILabel *mLabel= (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:23];
mLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: I just forgot to remove it.But I didn't add it for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your mainLabel is only initialised when a new cell is created. Write something like:

```
if (cell == nil)
{

    NSLog(@"in loop");

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


    mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 15)];
    mainLabel.tag = 100;

    [cell addSubview:mainLabel];
} else {
    mainLabel = [[cell viewWithTag:100] retain];
}
...
[mainLabel release];
```

Comment: The retain is very unwise.

Comment: @HotLicks: Why? I use only ARC and problably don't see the problem. But it seems to me that either alloc/initWithFrame or retain is balanced by a release.

Comment: Same here, it was a while ago when I used MRC for the last time, but from what I remember, this is how it works.

Comment: Well, the above sort of works, I suppose.  It would make far more sense, though, to simply release mainLabel in the if clause and not do the additional retain/release.